# how to extend jpa order

Tags: jpa, criteriaquery

I search table with Criteria Query and filter it with name field. i filter records that have name like %user-entered-name%.
then sort result with name column. now i have a problem. i will it sort like following:

- name (First list records that his name is equal to user entered name)
- name* (Second list records that his name starts with user entered name)
- `*name*` (In the last list records that hist name contains user entered name)

is there any solution for it in jpa.

thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to retrieve additional column called *relevance* using `CASE WHEN` statement. It could be defined as following:

```
c.multiselect(employee.get("name"),
    cb.selectCase()
    .when(cb.equal(employee.get("name"), "user-defined-name"), 3)
    .when(cb.like(employee.get("name"), "user-defined-name%"), 2)
    .when(cb.like(employee.get("name"), "%user-defined-name%"), 1)
    .otherwise(0)
    .alias("relevance"))
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but how can i set order by on this query. the second column of returned result doesn't have name.